How does the custom partition in flink work?
I'm currently working on a custom partitioner but I'm encountering some issues with my code. I've tried looking for documentation on the custom partitioner but have been unable to do so. If anyone has the documentation I would be extremely grateful :)
From what I understood, the custom partition didn't scale or at least would scale (the function partition(key, numPartitions) such that the class variables would be global.
As such I wanted to confirm if this was indeed the case.
If so how does it scale? and how can I effectively store a global hashmap as shown below in my code
some info on my custom partitionner:
it's based on a paper called holistic view on stream partitioning costs. Currently, it first checks if a key has already been seen or not if so it sends to the same partition otherwise it will look amongst all the choices it has and send to the one that has received the least amount.
package keygrouping;

import StringConstants.StringConstants;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.Partitioner;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class cam_n_all_in_one  implements Partitioner<String>, Serializable {
    public int n;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Set<String>> cardinality;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger> tupleCount;
    int parallelism;

    public EndWindowPropagation endWindowPropagation;

    public cam_n_all_in_one(int n_choices, int numPartitions) {
        endWindowPropagation = new EndWindowPropagation(parallelism);

        // n being the number of choices eg two choices etc...
        this.parallelism = numPartitions;
        this.n = n_choices;
        this.cardinality = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(numPartitions);
        this.tupleCount = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(numPartitions);
    }

    @Override
    public int partition(String key, int numPartitions){
        if(key.equals(StringConstants.WINDOW_END)){
            return endWindowPropagation.endWindowRouting();
        }
        return customPartition(key, numPartitions);
    }

    public int customPartition(String key, int numPartitions) {
        int[] hashes = generateHashes(key);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int partition = hashes[i];
            cardinality.putIfAbsent(partition, Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>()));
            tupleCount.putIfAbsent(partition, new AtomicInteger(0));

            Set<String> set = cardinality.get(partition);
            if (set.contains(key)) {
                tupleCount.get(partition).incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println("Choice: " + partition + " Key: " + key + " Partition: " + numPartitions + " TupleCount: " + tupleCount.get(partition).get() + " Cardinality: " + cardinality.get(partition).size());

                return partition;
            }
        }

        int minCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int choice = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int partition = hashes[i];
            cardinality.putIfAbsent(partition, Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>()));
            tupleCount.putIfAbsent(partition, new AtomicInteger(0));

            AtomicInteger count = tupleCount.get(partition);
            int currentCount = count.get();
            if (currentCount < minCount) {
                minCount = currentCount;
                choice = partition;
            }
        }

        cardinality.putIfAbsent(choice, Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>()));
        tupleCount.putIfAbsent(choice, new AtomicInteger(0));

        Set<String> set = cardinality.get(choice);
        synchronized (set) {
            set.add(key);
            tupleCount.get(choice).incrementAndGet();
        }
        System.out.println("Choice: " + choice + " Key: " + key + " Partition: " + numPartitions + " TupleCount: " + tupleCount.get(choice).get() + " Cardinality: " + cardinality.get(choice).size());

        return choice;
    }

    public int[] generateHashes(String input) {
        int[] hashes = new int[n];
        int baseHash = input.hashCode();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            hashes[i] = Math.abs((baseHash + i * 31) % this.parallelism); // Using a linear probing approach 31 helps distribute well
        }

        return hashes;
    }
}



